# Why yarn is warning in every move I made?

Tags: typescript, webpack, nativescript, yarnpkg

When ever I run `yarn global add ...` or `yarn global remove ...` it gives warnings such as ...

```sh
warning "nativescript > marked-terminal@3.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "marked@^0.4.0 || ^0.5.0".
warning "nativescript > nativescript-preview-sdk > tslint@5.4.3" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev".
warning "nativescript > nativescript-preview-sdk > tslint > tsutils@2.29.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.1.0 || >=2.1.0-dev || >=2.2.0-dev || >=2.3.0-dev || >=2.4.0-dev || >=2.5.0-dev || >=2.6.0-dev || >=2.7.0-dev || >=2.8.0-dev || >=2.9.0-dev || >= 3.0.0-dev || >= 3.1.0-dev".
```

or

`yarn add ...` and `yarn remove ...` commands give warnings such as ...

```sh
warning " > babel-loader@8.0.6" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=2".
warning "nativescript-dev-webpack > ts-loader@5.4.5" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
warning " > vue-loader@15.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "css-loader@*".
```

#### How to fix these dependency problems?

**NOTE**: It seems `yarn upgrade` and `yarn cache clean` do not help either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yarn` (but it would be the same if you used `npm` as a client) is warning you about unmet peer dependencies. [Peer dependencies](https://nodejs.org/ru/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) are different from your usual dependencies in that installing a module will *not* install its peer dependencies, with the implicit assumption that you already have them, or will need them anyway to use that package.

For example, `babel-loader` clearly needs `Webpack` to be used, and instead of bringing it in as a transitive dependency, it expects you to have it in your `package.json`.

There are a couple of situations where this does not work as expected:

- a package expects a peer dependency with a version, but you have a version number that is incompatible (it might still work though)
- a package might list a peer dependency which you really don't need - for example `eslint-config-react-app` requires a peer of `eslint-plugin-flowtype`, which is pointless if you are not using Flow.

How to fix this? by adding those dependencies to your project.